# Google Tag Manager - How to trigger multiple values from object

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I got an object with authors and brands. I want to track with Google Analytics which articles of which authors are read the most.

```
<script>
MY_OBJECT = {"Ben":["BMW"],"Michael":["Mercedes"],"Charles":["Chevrolet"]}
</script>
```

If I only want to track a single value I would create a custom variable and use this with a custom dimension in my general Google Analytics tag.

The number of authors can vary, it's not always three.

How can I trigger multiple values?

Comment: Are you tracking these are events or pageviews?

Comment: I want to fire an event with each pageview.

Comment: So sort of like...1. user visits the page, the "pageview" tag gets triggered, then an event tag gets triggered with Category "articles", action "read", label "Michael, Charles, Ben"?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate over the object. Since you have tagged this with Google Tag Manager I assume you want to use GTM, so instead of sending a tracking call directly you push the values to the dataLayer:

```
MY_OBJECT = {"Ben":["BMW"],"Michael":["Mercedes"],"Charles":["Chevrolet"]};
for(key in MY_OBJECT) { 
  dataLayer.push({"event":"push" , "author":key, "brand":MY_OBJECT[key].join(";")}); 
}
```

Now you create a trigger in GTM of the type "custom event" that listens to the custom event "push". You then create to datalayer variables "author" and "brand". For each iteration, the author variable will receive the key from your object (which is the author name).

Since "brand" is an array (even though there is only one array item per entry in your example) I have joined this into a string (using ";" as delimiter). You can now pass these variables to your event tracking tag, and have it fired on the "push" event (maybe you want to name this differently).

Comment: This crashes my Chrome browser when checking the tag manager with its preview. :-(